# Doctrine 2: Insert data to relations table

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, silex, multiple-tables, insert-into

I try insert data to database using silex framework. My database has 4 tables with relation. How can I insert data using insert function from Doctrine2? Do I need to add the data one by one to each table?

My code:

```
$app->post('/reservations/', function (Request $request) use ($app, $DataProvider) {

$insertData = $DataProvider->getRequestData();

$newClientId = $DataProvider->addReservation($insertData);

if(false == $newClientId){
    return $app->json(['errorMessage' => 'Can not insert user'], 500);
}

// $tables = $DataProvider->getClient($newClientId);

return $app->json(['message' => 'Client created!', 'client' => $clientDetails])
});

public function addReservation($data)
{
    print_r ($data);
    unset($data['userID']);
    $result = $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    $lastID = $this->db->lastInsertId();
    if(!$result){
        return false;
    }

    return $this->db->lastInsertId();
}
```

[image: My database structure:]

And my array which i try insert

```
Array ( [eventDate] => 11.02.2017 [bookingTime] => 10:00 [paid] => true [tableNumber] => 1 [name] => John[email] => pass123 [phone] => 1231231 )
```

Response from the server:

> DBALException in DBALException.php line 47:
>   An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO users (eventDate, bookingTime, paid, tableNumber, name, email, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["11.02.2017", "10:00", "true", "1", "John", "pass123", "1231231"]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'eventDate' in 'field list'

Comment: This array is wrong. Did you use the Form component? Are you using the ORM? How are the entities mapped?

Comment: Ok thanks, actually I was in angular service with http.post send map instead array :)